# Threading Gives No Output in Python 3.6

Tags: python, multithreading, output

Here's my code:

```
import _thread
import time
def print_time(name, delay):
    count=1
    while count<=5:
        time.delay(delay)
        print ("Thread %s Time is %s"%(count, time.ctime(time.time())))
        count = count+1

_thread.start_new_thread(print_time,("T-1",2))
_thread.start_new_thread(print_time,("T-2",4))
```

The output should be various lines telling the current time. But after running the program I got no output and no error. Why is this happening? I use Python 3.6.

Comment: Use the multiprocessing library

Comment: multiprocessing https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Given the sample doesn't contain any actual work, there's no indication the multiprocessing module would be any more appropriate. It is useful for message passing programs and using multiple processors for Python code, but has its own caveats (in particular, the lack of fork on Windows, and the serialization of data passed between processes).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the first question is why you're using `_thread`. I am guessing your issue is that your main thread finishes before `print_time` manages to produce any output, and on this particular system, that exits the whole program.

From the section Caveats in the [_thread documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html):

> When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other threads survive. On most systems, they are killed without executing `try` … `finally` clauses or executing object destructors.

When using `threading` instead, you get to choose whether to await threads with the `daemon` argument.

Comment: Can't we use the `thread` module? I'm currently learning proxy servers and they use the `thread` module.

Comment: Sure you can... you just have to pay attention and handle all the details. Or you can use the modules in the standard library that already do that. In this case, you expected an implicit synchronization (probably in the form of joining all threads to the main thread) but you needed to make it explicit.

Comment: My system says `ImportError: no module named thread`. What should I do?

Comment: I thought you meant `_thread`, which is in the standard library. It's quite low level. I don't know what you're trying to do; if you're using Python 3.6, it's likely a good idea to look at [concurrent futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) which provides a common high level interface to run tasks in either threads or processes.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are always the better options but if you still insist on doing with `_thread` module just delay the main thread by adding `time.sleep(1)` at the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `threading`:

```
import threading
import time

def print_time(name, delay):
    count=1
    while count<=5:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print ("Thread %s Time is %s"%(count, time.ctime(time.time())))
        count = count+1

t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_time, args=("T-1",2))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_time, args=("T-2",4))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

> The threading module provides an easier to use and higher-level threading API built on top of this [`_thread`] module.